# IOS architecture 64bits

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect

Our phonegap app builds fine for the iphone simulator but generates linker errors when building the app on an iphone. the only thing that changed was installing testflight and a test app.

We already removed testflight and the test app, but the linker errors remain.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

We're on xcode 6.2 and ordova 3.4.0

Errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/gusph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/momitSHDApp-evgpydfzbrlcmzazjhmquxttnqnq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/gusph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/momitSHDApp-evgpydfzbrlcmzazjhmquxttnqnq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CDVPageDidLoadNotification", referenced from:
      -[CDVSplashScreen pluginInitialize] in CDVSplashScreen.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVWebViewDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVInvokedUrlCommand", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVFile.o
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVFile.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVUserAgentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NotificationsNode in NotificationsNode.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCamera in CDVCamera.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVBattery in CDVBattery.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVContacts in CDVContacts.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[CDVInAppBrowser openInSystem:] in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NotificationsNode.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVConnection.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVCamera.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVBattery.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVContacts.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVAccelerometer.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NotificationsNode in NotificationsNode.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCamera in CDVCamera.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVBattery in CDVBattery.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVContacts in CDVContacts.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

This linker error message is the key:

```
.../libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)
```

Static and dynamic libraries under OSX and iOS are *fat* in that they can hold code for multiple CPU architectures.  That library doesn't have the `arm64` architecture and therefore cannot be used.

The solution is to get a version that does support `arm64`.  If you are building that library then you are not including the CPU architecture when building it.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html):

```
This means that starting at that time, Cordova-based apps 
should be built using a version of Cordova that has 64-bit iOS support.

The first version of Cordova to include 64-bit for iOS is 3.4.1. 
Therefore, to meet these requirements of the Apple App Store, you should be 
using at least version 3.4.1 of Cordova before this February deadline.
```

Make sure you are using a version of Cordova that has the 64bit architecture built in.  You appear to be currently using one without (an old version).

Answer (score 0):

remove arm64 from Valid Architectures of CordovaLib Targets,
Also set 'NO' to Build Active Architecture Only,
Make same settings to Main app.